# Possible solution for 'Cannot invoke createMimeMessage() because...' error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, controller, repository

[I am given image for reference with above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDPRm.png)

I want to call another class method. its mail sender using smtp. mail send methods and generate otp methods also not working. How will short this problem. i am using java 17 version